Generate a pkcs8 key suitable for ECDSA private key import using subtlecrypto
I need to generate a deterministic set ECDSA keys using zero dependencies javascript, for which I produce a pkcs8 key out of raw bytes and then import it as ECDSA private key. Is this logically possible and if so what's wrong with the code below, as it gives me DataError error during the import call.
// Example function to convert derived bits to a PKCS#8 formatted key and import it
function convertRawKeyToPKCS8(rawKey, curveOid) {
    // PKCS#8 header for ECDSA with the chosen curve OID
    const pkcs8Header = [
        0x30, 0x81, 0x87,       // SEQUENCE (header, total length)
        0x02, 0x01, 0x00,       // INTEGER (version 0)
        0x30, 0x13,             // SEQUENCE (AlgorithmIdentifier header)
        0x06, 0x07,             // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (1.2.840.10045.2.1 - ecPublicKey OID)
        0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01,
        0x06, 0x08,             // OBJECT IDENTIFIER for curve (this is curve specific, provided as parameter)
        ...curveOid,
        0x04, 0x6d,             // OCTET STRING (privateKey length follows)
        0x30, 0x6b,             // SEQUENCE
        0x02, 0x01, 0x01,       // INTEGER (version 1)
        0x04, 0x20              // OCTET STRING (private key length, 32 bytes for P-256)
    ];

    // Append the raw private key bytes
    const pkcs8Key = new Uint8Array(pkcs8Header.length + rawKey.length);
    pkcs8Key.set(pkcs8Header);
    pkcs8Key.set(rawKey, pkcs8Header.length);

    return pkcs8Key;
}

// Example OIDs for different elliptic curves:
const OID_P256 = [0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07]; // P-256 curve OID

// Example raw ECDSA private key for P-256 (32 bytes):
const rawPrivateKey = new Uint8Array([
    0x93, 0x6a, 0x62, 0x91, 0x62, 0xa9, 0xba, 0x46,
    0x0c, 0x12, 0xfa, 0xb7, 0xdb, 0xe0, 0x2f, 0x91,
    0x52, 0xfa, 0xd2, 0xda, 0x47, 0x9a, 0x7d, 0xf2,
    0xbe, 0xab, 0xaa, 0x04, 0x48, 0x67, 0x6b, 0xa1
]);

// Generate the PKCS#8 key
const pkcs8Key = convertRawKeyToPKCS8(rawPrivateKey, OID_P256);

// Log the resulting PKCS#8 key as a hexadecimal string for display (optional)
console.log(Array.from(pkcs8Key).map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''));

// Use the SubtleCrypto API to import the PKCS#8 key
async function importECDSAPrivateKey(pkcs8Key) {
    const privateKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        pkcs8Key.buffer,
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        true,    // Extractable
        ["sign"] // Key usage
    );
    return privateKey;
}

// Example usage
importECDSAPrivateKey(pkcs8Key).then(privateKey => {
    console.log('Private key imported:', privateKey);
}).catch(console.error);


The created ASN.1/DER key is invalid, as you can check with an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/.

Thanks, how do I produce the valid one please?

For a valid ASN.1/DER, the lengths must be adjusted in three places, see here. However, as already mentioned in the answer, not all browsers support PKCS#8 keys without public component, e.g. it works with Chrome, but not with Firefox. Alternatively, as described in the answer, you can of course also add the public component (which you would have to calculate if you don't have it).

There are two issues:

The first sequence length is only 0x87 when the public key is included. Since you're not adding a public key, the length is invalid.

You'll face problems in Firefox and Safari if you try loading an EC private key without public key.


The solution to both problems is to incldue the public key:
// Example function to convert derived bits to a PKCS#8 formatted key and import it
function convertRawKeyToPKCS8(rawPrivateKey, rawPublicKey, curveOid) {
    // PKCS#8 header for ECDSA with the chosen curve OID
    let pkcs8Key = [
        0x30, 0x81, 0x87,       // SEQUENCE (header, total length)
        0x02, 0x01, 0x00,       // INTEGER (version 0)
        0x30, 0x13,             // SEQUENCE (AlgorithmIdentifier header)
        0x06, 0x07,             // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (1.2.840.10045.2.1 - ecPublicKey OID)
        0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01,
        0x06, 0x08,             // OBJECT IDENTIFIER for curve (this is curve specific, provided as parameter)
        ...curveOid,
        0x04, 0x6d,             // OCTET STRING (privateKey length follows)
        0x30, 0x6b,             // SEQUENCE
        0x02, 0x01, 0x01,       // INTEGER (version 1)
        0x04, 0x20,             // OCTET STRING (private key length, 32 bytes for P-256)
        ...rawPrivateKey,
        0xa1, 0x44,             // [1] (tag)
        0x03, 0x42,             // BIT STRING (public key length, 66 bytes for P-256)
        ...rawPublicKey,
    ];

    return new Uint8Array(pkcs8Key);
}


// Example OIDs for different elliptic curves:
const OID_P256 = [0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07]; // P-256 curve OID

// Example raw ECDSA private key for P-256 (32 bytes):
const rawPrivateKey = [
    0x17, 0x4f, 0xa3, 0x30, 0xdb, 0xd7, 0xf9, 0x66,
    0xee, 0xb2, 0x36, 0xcc, 0xbc, 0x29, 0xb0, 0x25,
    0x5a, 0xd2, 0xcf, 0x0c, 0x91, 0x06, 0x9a, 0x9f,
    0x33, 0x53, 0x37, 0x24, 0x87, 0x8e, 0x03, 0x2b,
];
const rawPublicKey = [
    0x00, 0x04, 0x87, 0x44, 0x7e, 0xc5, 0xc8, 0xff,
    0xfb, 0x77, 0xf7, 0x24, 0x0d, 0xdd, 0x8b, 0xa2,
    0x03, 0x8b, 0xf9, 0x7c, 0x3b, 0x86, 0x4a, 0xb8,
    0x4b, 0xb1, 0xea, 0x3d, 0x3a, 0xe2, 0x2f, 0xca,
    0xbf, 0xb1, 0xfe, 0xbd, 0xf4, 0xda, 0x4b, 0xfd,
    0x12, 0x30, 0x79, 0xe2, 0x8b, 0x3b, 0x35, 0xae,
    0x22, 0x2b, 0x06, 0xd2, 0xd2, 0x26, 0x24, 0x6f,
    0x95, 0x5a, 0xa2, 0x51, 0x87, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x41,
    0xdd, 0x67,
]

// Generate the PKCS#8 key
const pkcs8Key = convertRawKeyToPKCS8(rawPrivateKey, rawPublicKey, OID_P256);

// Log the resulting PKCS#8 key as a hexadecimal string for display (optional)
console.log(Array.from(pkcs8Key).map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''));

// Use the SubtleCrypto API to import the PKCS#8 key
async function importECDSAPrivateKey(pkcs8Key) {
    const privateKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        pkcs8Key.buffer,
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        true,    // Extractable
        ["sign"] // Key usage
    );
    return privateKey;
}

// Example usage
importECDSAPrivateKey(pkcs8Key).then(privateKey => {
    console.log('Private key imported:', privateKey);
}).catch(console.error);

And here's the PKCS#8 structure of the example above:
PrivateKeyInfo SEQUENCE (3 elem)

    version Version INTEGER 0
    privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        algorithm OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ecPublicKey (ANSI X9.62 public key type)
        parameters ANY OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 prime256v1 (ANSI X9.62 named elliptic curve)
    privateKey PrivateKey OCTET STRING (109 byte) 306B0201010420174FA330DBD7F966EEB236CCBC29B0255AD2CF0C91069A9F3353372…
        SEQUENCE (3 elem)
            INTEGER 1
            OCTET STRING (32 byte) 174FA330DBD7F966EEB236CCBC29B0255AD2CF0C91069A9F33533724878E032B
            [1] (1 elem)
                BIT STRING (520 bit) 0000010010000111010001000111111011000101110010001111111111111011011101…

Note it's a different key pair because I needed one with a public key.

Thanks for this. I'm using mnemonics (something like BIP39) + salt (password) to generate the seed, then I use that seed to produce the key (currently hardcoded as private bytes). Thus my inputs are just a byte array, I wonder how public keys fits into this "flow"? In theory I should be able to produce a public key out of private one, can it be done dynamically in my case?

@JsCoder If you're doing this all in a browser, you'll need some elliptic curve operations.  WebCrypto is quite limited and doesn't expose this kind of functions, so you'll probably have to implement it yourself. I'd suggest asking it in a separate question, to not confuse with the ASN.1 stuff.

Sure, I'll setup a bounty for this. I'm looking to get a set of ECDSA keys using Mnemonics + Slat as inputs.

@JsCoder Another alternative I just found: JWT allows only private keys, so if you can generate your key as "x" and "y" points you can write and load JWT instead of PKCS#8.

Thanks, I'm totally new to this stuff, I saw that it can be accomplished by using generateKey, but I need a deterministic ways, so the private keys can be restored.
